# Can I use tcpdump to analyze binary data - gRPC, http2, MessagePack, etc?

Tags: tcpdump

Life is simple with text-encoded formats like JSON. I can see enough text in the dump to figure out where something can be wrong. But with the growing popularity of binary interchange formats, I think tcpdump no longer makes the cut. Am I right to say that?

If yes, what are other viable alternatives to analyze the formats I mentioned in the question?

Answer (score 1):

[`tcpdump`](https://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html) is used to **capture** and dump network packets.

To do actual analysis on captured packets you usually need what is called a [packet analyzer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_analyzer) with protocol decode capabilities. Wikipedia maintains a [useful list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_packet_analyzers) as does the [wireshark team](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Tools) .

Wireshark has plugins for decoding a [large number of protocols](https://wiki.wireshark.org/ProtocolReference)